# Mongo DB, PHP add or update a field in a document

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following document:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5241f1d79b7e7aed05000000"),
   "description": {
     "nl": "Hallo",
     "en": "Hello"
    },
  "name": "Marc"
}
```

Now I need to update to update one existing field or add new field to the description. In php I use the update function for Mongo and the following code:

```
$new_data = array(
    '$set' => array(
    "description" => array(
         "de" => "hallo"
       )
    )
);
```

What it does it removes all other fields and just insert the "de" field. I tried replacing $set with $push (which I thought was made for this) but no result also $setOnInsert does not do anything.

How can I solve this problem so that I can either add a new field (if it does not exist) or update if it exist.

Thanks

Comment: before updating also add previous record in $new_data in description because think logically you are updating filed

Comment: That makes sort of sense, but that means in some cases I need to send e.g. 23 extra fields in a post that are not updated. There is no other way?

Comment: you can add more fields but in your case description is array and you are replacing with other value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your update like

```
{$set: {"description.de": "hello"}}
```

I guess in your code it would be:

```
$new_data = array(
  '$set' => array(
    "description.de" => "hallo"
  )
);
```